# findViewById changes all occurrences in for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, layout-inflater

I have the following method which adds a view `Views` to a `LinearLayout`, and for each view a progress is set on a `ProgressBar`:

```
private void showProgress(LinearLayout recentLayout) {
    recentLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (MyItem mItem : items) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_content, recentLayout, false);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.listview_content_progress);

        // [...] simplifying a lot

        // mItem.getProgress().progess  --> float between 0 and 1
        progressBar.setProgress((int) (mItem.getProgress().progess * 100));

        recentLayout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

**However** after executing this code **each progressbar** in the layout has the same progress (in detail, the progress of the very last element) set to it.

What am I missing? For me it looks like each progressbar's progress is set individually and not at once at the end.

**EDIT**

I don't know if this might be because i use a custom progress drawable via xml.
Do I have to mutate it manuall?

Comment: @TimCastelijns the weird thing is, that's not true. (it works in 1 iteration (async with finals) and in another it doesn't. As you can see the progressbar is accessed by the inflated view, therefore only exactly the one i need is returned.

Comment: What values are you passing to `setProgress()`? What is the max value of `progressBar`?

Comment: @clever_trevor integers between 0 and 100.  This is not the problem as it works fine in other parts of the code (max val is 100)

Comment: Try passing null for the view group.   `final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_content, null, false);`  I'm pretty sure android is trying to conserve resources and is returning the same view everytime

Comment: @VirtualProdigy unfortunately not, same issue occures

Comment: just to be sure I would try to Log `mItem.getProgress().progess * 100` right before the setProgress and see if they actually have different values

Comment: @IvoBeckers It's actually coded like this and logged to logcat and just simplified for SO

Comment: @Sebastianschneider you should not ask for upvotes, especially not in your question

Comment: Try to remove the `final`

Answer (score 0):

If you use drawable for progressBar's "background". It's an issue.

All progressBars have the same drawable as background (or progress status). When you set progress status to one of them, it changes drawable, and it's applied to all progress bars.

It's a "common" issue.

I've faced it in Horocope app. There were just 3 progress bar, so i done it on non good way :D

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.love_progressbar));
progressBar2.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.job_progressbar));
progressBar3.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.health_progressbar));

progressBar.setProgress(love);
progressBar2.setProgress(job);
progressBar3.setProgress(health);
```